# Initialize GenericArray<u8, Self::KeySize> for aead::NewAead

Tags: rust, rust-cargo

I am trying to implement [Aead](https://docs.rs/aead/0.2.0/aead/index.html) encryption for a project. For what I understood I first have to create 
a stateless AEAD by calling aead::NewAead::new() which takes a [GenericArray](https://docs.rs/generic-array/0.13.2/generic_array/index.html) as parameter. I initialize this array by calling `let aeas_key = GenericArray::from([1u8; 32]);` then I use the key as follow `let new_aead = NewAead::new(aeas_key);` and it outputs the following error:

```
 = note: expected struct `generic_array::GenericArray<u8, _>`
   found struct `generic_array::GenericArray<u8, typenum::uint::UInt<typenum::uint::UInt<typenum::uint::UInt<typenum::uint::UInt<typenum::uint::UInt<typenum::uint::UTerm, typenum::bit::B1>,
   typenum::bit::B0>, typenum::bit::B1>, typenum::bit::B0>, typenum::bit::B0>>`
 = note: perhaps two different versions of crate `generic_array` are being used?
```

I know that the size of the GenericArray needs to be unsigned, so I tried the following:

```
   let len = ArrayLength::<32>;
   let aeas_key = GenericArray::<1u8, len>;
   let new_aead = NewAead::new(aeas_key);
```

But this gives me:

```
 "type arguments must be declared prior to const arguments" at the line:
 let aeas_key = GenericArray::<1u8, len>;
```

Here is my Cargo.toml file:

```
[package]
name = "..."
version = "0.1.0"
authors = ["..."]
edition = "2018"

[lib]
name = "DecDbApi"
crate-type = ["cdylib"]

[dependencies.pyo3]
git = "https://github.com/PyO3/pyo3"
features = ["extension-module"]

[dependencies]
sha2 = "0.8.1"
hex = "0.4.0"
serde_json = "1.0"
igd = "0.10.0"
serde = { version = "1.0", features = ["derive"] }
aead = "0.2.0"
generic-array = "0.13.2"
typenum = "1.11.2"
```

Does anyone knows what the problem is ? 
Thank you.

Comment: Have you tried switching around 1u8 and len?

Comment: I just tried and now I get  "let len = ArrayLength::<16>; not a value"

Comment: Please, show your `Cargo.toml`, your first issue is there.

Comment: @Boiethios I added it

Comment: What if you use `generic-array = "*"` and `typenum = "*"`?

Comment: This gives me an error " NewAead::<aeas_key>; non-constant value" and " NewAead::<aeas_key>;  not a value" I guess I have to take more time to understand the library